# mod_rewrite and GoDaddy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really have only a fair idea of what I am doing. Sorry.

This is what I did to rewrite URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/news/1-category-name/2-item-name
http://example.com/foo/bar/news/1-category-name
```

into these:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/news.php?newsID=2
http://example.com/foo/bar/news-categories.php?categID=1
```

respectively

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /foo/bar
  RewriteRule ^news\/([^\/]+)/([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)$   news.php?newsID=$3
  RewriteRule ^news\/([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)$            news-categories.php?categID=$1
</IfModule>
```

But whenever I try this URL:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/news/16-news-category-1/11-title
```

It always returns a `404` error:

*The requested URL /foo/bar/news.html/16-news-category-1/11-title was not found on this server*

Why is it trying to find `news.html`? What am I doing wrong?

I don't know if this is relevant but `example.com` is *virtual* (I really don't know the term). The actual files can also be accessed via `http://real-domain.com/qux/`. So you'd do `http://real-domain.com/qux/foo/bar/news/1-category-name/2-item-name` to get to `2-item-name`.

Does it also help to say that this script actually runs on my development machine?

```
Development:
   PHP v5.3.5
   Apache v2.2

Live:
   PHP v5.3.6
   Apache v2.2
```

Comment: you have a rewritebase to /foo/bar?

Comment: No I dont. That's the actual content of the `.htaccess` nothing more related to `mod_rewrite`. I will try to put a `RewriteBase`

Comment: @Zeus: Adding `RewriteBase /foo/bar` didn't help. Updating the question...

Comment: Is foo/bar exists? where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: @Zeus, yes `foo/bar` exists. The `.htaccess` is at `foo/bar`

Comment: Is there any other conflict with httpd.conf or .htaccess?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3602/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-rolando-cruz)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)-([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)(\/?)$ /news.php?newsID=$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)(\/?)$ /news.php?newsID=$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)-([0-9]+)(\/?)$ /news-categories.php?categID=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-z\-]+)(\/?)$ /news-categories.php?categID=$1 [L,NC]
```

so when someone goes to:

```
news/11-category-12 or
news/11-category-12/ or
news/11-category or
news/11-category/
```

it goes to: `news-categories.php?categID=11`

and when someone goes to:

```
news/11-category-12/1-title or
news/11-category-12/1-title/ or
news/11-category/1-title or
news/11-category/1-title/
```

it goes to: `news.php?newsID=1`

Also, make sure the .htaccess is at the root of the public_html folder as well of news.php and news-categories.php